# Common Lisp case and quoted elements

Tags: common-lisp, case, quote

I'm writing a dungeon crawler game in CL, and I'm having trouble with the case form.

Two things:

- Common Lisp complains `Duplicate keyform QUOTE in CASE statement`
- `(make-instance 'cl-rogue:tile tile-type 'wall)` should print as "#", but the object prints as " " no matter which tile-type I use.

The code:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage :cl-rogue
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export
    :*rows*
    :*cols*
    :*levels*
    :tile
    :tile-type
    :tile-contents
    :tile-hidden
    :tile-locked
    :tile-closed
    :main))

(in-package :cl-rogue)

(defparameter *cols* 80)
(defparameter *rows* 24)
(defparameter *levels* 26)
```

The class:

```
(defclass tile ()
  ((tile-type
    :initarg :tile-type
    :accessor tile-type
    :initform 'floor
    :documentation "Type of tile")
    (tile-contents
      :initarg :tile-contents
      :accessor tile-contents
      :initform '()
      :documentation "Any items the tile holds")
    (tile-hidden
      :initarg :tile-hidden
      :accessor tile-hidden
      :initform nil
      :documentation "Whether the tile is hidden or shown")
    (tile-locked
      :initarg :tile-locked
      :accessor tile-locked
      :initform nil
      :documentation "Whether the tile is locked")
    (tile-closed
      :initarg :tile-closed
      :accessor tile-closed
      :initform nil
      :documentation "Whether the tile is open or closed")))
```

The print method:

```
(defmethod print-object ((object tile) stream)
  (with-slots (tile-type tile-contents tile-hidden tile-locked tile-closed) object
    (if tile-hidden
      (format stream " ")
      (let ((an-item (car tile-contents)))
        (if an-item
          (format stream "~a" an-item)
          (format stream (case tile-type
            ('wall "#")
            ('upstair "<")
            ('downstair ">")
            ('door (if tile-closed "+" "\\"))
            (otherwise " "))))))))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to quote the symbols in `CASE`.

**Actually you shouldn't quote symbols in `CASE` clauses.**

See: **this is wrong**

```
CL-USER 31 > (case 'quote
               ('not-quote 'oops-really-quote)
               ('quote 'it-is-a-quote))
OOPS-REALLY-QUOTE
```

Above is the unintended consequence of using `'not-quote` instead of the correct unquoted `not-quote`.

The following is correct:

```
CL-USER 32 > (case 'quote
               (not-quote 'oops-really-quote)
               (quote 'it-is-a-quote))
IT-IS-A-QUOTE
```

**The syntax of CASE in Common Lisp**

```
case keyform
  {normal-clause}*
  [otherwise-clause]

=> result*

normal-clause::= (keys form*) 
otherwise-clause::= ({otherwise | t} form*) 
clause::= normal-clause | otherwise-clause 
keys ::= object | (object*)
```

As you can see the keys are either a single object or a list of objects. The objects are not evaluated.

**Symbols in CASE clauses are not evaluated.**

```
(case tile-type
  (wall ...)
  (door ...))
```

`WALL` and `DOOR` are purely symbols and not evaluated as variables.

The Lisp reader reads `'foo`as `(quote foo)`.

You wrote:

```
(case tile-type
  ('wall ...)
  ('door ...))
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
(case tile-type
  ((quote wall) ...)
  ((quote door) ...))
```

But you can't quote a symbol in `CASE`. You have to provide the symbols as literal constants.

If you write:

```
(let ((bar 'foo)
      (baz 'foo))
  (case bar
    (baz :we-have-a-foo-through-baz)
    (foo :we-really-have-a-foo)))
```

This returns `:WE-REALLY-HAVE-A-FOO`. Because `CASE` uses constant data, not variables.

`CASE` accepts a list of items. Since you have `QUOTE` as a symbol in more than clause, the compiler showed a warning.

As I said, there is no quoting possible, since the items are not evaluated.

As for `CASE` accepting a list of items in the clauses, it looks like this:

```
(case tile-type
  ((door wall) ...)
  ((floor window painting) ...))
```

For the `WALL` symbol, you need to make sure that it is in the right package when you create the object.

Better use a keyword symbol, such as `:wall`. Then you don't need to export it and there is no confusion about in which package the symbol is.

**About the formatting of the code**:
You had a bullet list and right after it a code section. This is not rendered as you expect. I have added the text 'The code:' before the code. Then the rendering works as expected.

Comment: @mcandre: code after an enumeration is not recognized. You need to enter a piece of text first, then the code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that. I thought the syntax was (case something (this do-this) (that do-that) (otherwise do-otherwise))

Comment: This is a beautiful answer.