# Quoting match clause in CASE

Tags: common-lisp

### Update

I think I understand what's going on. Lisp percieves only the `'` part of the match clauses `'(1 2 3)` and `'(41 42 43)` as the key (because they both expand to `(Quote`... and from this perspective the second `'` = `(QUOTE`... in the third code snippet is a "duplicate key" (while in fact it isn't a key at all. It's just a syntax error on my part).

I think my main problem was that I didn't understand the compiler warning correctly.

### Original Post

I don't understand the following behaviour of `case` (or of sbcl).

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510317/common-lisp-case-and-quoted-elements) SO posting R. Joswig points out that the match clauses of a `case` form are not evaluated and treated as literals. Hence match clauses should not be quoted.

Unaware of this, i quoted one match clause but forgot to quote the other. What I don't understand is, why the compiler doesn't complain if I quote one match clause, but does complain if I quote both of them. Specifically:

```
> (let ((x 42))
     (case x
       ((1 2 3) 'first-branch)
       ('(41 42 43) 'second-branch)))      ; <=  second match clause quoted
NIL
```

=> No Warning.

```
> (let ((x 42))
     (case x
       ('(1 2 3) 'first-branch)            ; <=  first match clause quoted
       ((41 42 43) 'second-branch)))
NIL
```

=> No Warning either.

```
> (let ((x 42))
     (case x
       ('(1 2 3) 'first-branch)            ; <=  both quoted
       ('(41 42 43) 'second-branch)))      ; <=  
NIL
```

=> **style warning:**

```
 ; caught STYLE-WARNING:
 ;  Duplicate key QUOTE in CASE form, occurring in the first clause:
 ;     ('(1 2 3) 'FIRST-BRANCH), and the second clause:
 ;     ('(41 42 43) 'SECOND-BRANCH).
```

Why is it that compiler complains only if I quote two match clauses but doesn't if I only quote one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `case` is not evaluated, so when you `quote` both cases, the code is equivalent to:

```
(let ((x 2 ))
 (case x
   ((QUOTE (1 2 3)) 'first-branch)           
   ((QUOTE (41 42 43)) 'second-branch)))
```

which means your have literal `QUOTE` in both form, which caused the warning message.

Comment: Yes, thanks. You said it more concisely. `'` expands to `(QUOTE ` and because of the whitespace after `QUOTE` Lisp "thinks" that I intended only the literal `QUOTE` as the match clause. And because I have `'` in front of both lines Lisp thinks I have a duplicate key `Quote` (apart from the fact that my syntax is flawed anyhow).

Comment: The whitespace has nothing to do with it.  You match in both forms either the symbol named `quote` or the given literal list of three elements.  The clauses are not evaluated.

Comment: What they meant was that the whitespace is a list item separator, and `ecase` ends up seeing both `QUOTE` and the actual value they quoted as two items in the same list thanks to the whitespace... the original expression had no whitespace, hence it looked like a single value. That's the crux of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just to make it clear: the quote symbol is here just another symbol without any specific meaning. Common Lisp expects in the head of the clause of a `case` expression either a constant atom like `foo` or a list of constant atoms like `(foo bar baz)`. Also notice that Lisp uses `eql` as comparison - thus it does compare for identity or value in case of numbers and characters, but not for content.

This example shows that `quote` is just another symbol in the case of `case` clauses:

```
CL-USER> (case 2
           ((quote foo) 'foo)
           ((quote bar) 'bar))
WARNING: Duplicate key QUOTE in CASE form, occurring in the first clause:
  ('FOO 'FOO), and the second clause:
  ('BAR 'BAR).
NIL
```

If we write `baz` instead of `quote` we get the same warning:

```
CL-USER> (case 2
           ((baz foo) 'foo)
           ((baz bar) 'bar))
WARNING: Duplicate key BAZ in CASE form, occurring in the first clause:
  ((BAZ FOO) 'FOO), and the second clause:
  ((BAZ BAR) 'BAR).
NIL
```

Comment: I now understand why it fails, but this answer offers no solution. Can someone clarify what you need to do to properly match on an identifier like `'foo`?

Comment: @renato  `'foo` is not an identifier. `'foo` is a list of two symbols `(QUOTE FOO)`. Just don't quote it.

Comment: Ah, `case` does not evaluate the first form in each branch :) that's all I needed to understand. Thanks.